# Create a sortable, ranked list with Google Sheets

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, spreadsheet, ranking

I'd like to create a sortable, ranked/ordered list with Google Sheets. Each row will have multiple, sortable columns.

The issue is that when I add an item or edit its ranking, I'll have to manually update the ranking of each of the following items...unless someone knows another way (which I'm sure they do).

*E.g.*

**Rank** | **Title** | **Year**

1...Sexy Sadie...1968
2...A Day in the Life...1967
3...I've Just Seen A Face...1965

Comment: Let's say it's a playlist, but it can be sorted by the other columns, too.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to drop the Rank column and freeze the first row (Display > Freeze > 1 Row). You can now sort by row and you ranking would be determined by the grey row count bar on the right of the screen.